# Emulating ANSI colour escape codes in Python curses

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I'm trying to display "text images" generated by [tiv](https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer) in my python-curses application. Of course, I canot just print the text because (n)curses doesn't handle the escape sequences so I have to do it myself. I'm stuck on how to do the background colour. Here is a snippet of code:

```py
def makeData(data):
    out = []
    pos = 0
    ccol = ()
    while pos < len(data):
        if ord(data[pos]) == 27: #if it's a colour escape sequence
            pos += 2
            if data[pos] == "0": pos += 2; continue #tiv resets after every line, ignore that
            if data[pos] == "4": fg = False; bg = True
            else: fg = True; bg = False
            pos += 5 #skip 8;5;
            num = ""
            while data[pos] != "m":
                num += data[pos]
                pos += 1
            num = int(num)
            pos += 1
            ccol = (fg, bg, num)
        else: #otherwise, add the character with the current colour to the buffer
            out.append((ccol, data[pos]))
            pos += 1
    return out

def main(stdscr):
    curses.use_default_colors()
    for i in range(0, curses.COLORS):
    curses.init_pair(i + 1, i, -1)

    y = 1
    x = 1
    for char in self.data:
        if char[1] == "\n":
            y += 1
            x = 1
        else:
            self.s.addstr(y, x, char[1], curses.color_pair(char[0][2]))
            x += 1
                
    self.s.refresh()
```

This works to parse the foreground and background colours however I am stuck on how to print the characters with the correct background. Right now, it works with the correct foreground but no background.

Any help would be much appriciated, including "this code is bad do this instead" :)

Comment: Those who voted to close: please elaborate why, since I can avoid the mistake next time

Comment: The third parameter to `init_pair` is the background color, and `-1` tells ncurses to (try to) use the terminal's default color.

Comment: @ThomasDickey yeah but the issue is that I need 256 colours for the background *and* 256 colours for the foreground, i.e. every colour combination. That would require 65536 colours which afaik curses doesn't support.

Comment: It's done that for a few years (ncurses 6.1 in 2018 - see [announcement](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.1.html#h3-database)).

Comment: It takes time for python itself to catch up, but the [3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/curses.html#curses.has_extended_color_support) page states that it supports the ncurses 6.1 features.

Comment: @ThomasDickey ah that's why it wasn't working, I'm still on 2.2

Comment: @ThomasDickey ok so I have ncurses 6.2 and python 3.9 but still `import curses; curses.version` reports 2.2. What can I do?

Comment: There are different python arrangements - some use "python3" and "python2" to allow both, and use a symbolic link for "python".  Whether 3.9 has what you need is a different matter - 3.10 is what the documentation said.

Comment: @ThomasDickey yeah I figured it out, long story short I thought 3.10 was the *curses* version I needed. Installing python3.10 now (And I made a mistake even with that: I thought 3.10 == 3.1 haha. Too much maths I'd say)

Comment: sounds good (I'm curious how well the Python developers used the changes in ncurses 6.1).  fwiw, there was never an ncurses 2.x or 3.x (it went from 1x. to 4.0 in 1996 as mentioned in the licensing page).

Comment: @ThomasDickey yeah well since `curses.version` in python returned `2.2` I assumed the python curses module's latest version was 3.10

Comment: @ThomasDickey well now I have another issue... It still doesn't seem to work. I'll make a seperate post for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64078902/python-curses-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-more-than-256-colour-pairs